# How to implement sub-query in Microstratergy?

Tags: subquery, microstrategy, inner-query

Please give me guidance on how to implement the following query in **Microstratergy**.

> SELECT   batch_nr,check_nr,update_ts
>       FROM
>       claim_financial_transaction_dim a,
>       ***(select max(update_ts) update_ts,check_nr,batch_nr from claim_financial_transaction_dim group by check_nr)max***   where
>       ROW_END_TS IN ('9999-12-31 00:00:00') AND a.check_nr IN ('045-4254355') and a.update_ts=max.update_ts and
>   a.check_nr=max.check_nr

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, you don't implement SQL queries in MicroStrategy. You model your business entities in your schema, and MicroStrategy writes the SQL.

There are, however, some exceptions. You can use a Freeform SQL report, which allows you to write the SQL for a report yourself. This is somewhat inflexible, as this report cannot be modified by anyone using it (by, for example, drilling to a different level of data).

Alternatively, you can create a Logical Table in MicroStrategy, which allows you to write a single pass of SQL, and then map schema objects onto it. This SQL will be typically be used as a sub-query in the query MicroStrategy. This is sometimes known as the My DBA Won't Allow Me To Create Views functionality.

It does sound however, that you need to go back and understand how MicroStrategy works fundamentally. If you're working back from a query to MSTR, you're (probably) going about things the wrong way.